# Structuring of data in Rust

Tags: data-structures, rust

I'm trying to convert an old personal Java project into Rust as a learning experience. The basic data structure looked like this:

- There is one main `Library`. The `Library` has a list of authors, and a list of books.
- Each author also has a list of books he/she has written.
- Each book has a reference to its author.

In the Java program I took a decision that there should never exist more than one object for each book ("The Hobbit") in the program. If a new book (maybe through user input) entered the system the first thing I would do was to test if it was already in the `Library`, and then replace the user input with the book-object from the `Library`. This vastly simplified a lot of logic since you could always count on comparing books by reference was valid.

Anyway, I am now rewriting this code in Rust and I have run into a problem regarding organizing my data in memory.

Having a `Library` with a collection of `Authors` is straight forward. However, how do I organize my books?

In Java the `Library` contained a `HashMap` with all the books which made it possible to find a book in constant time. Each `Author` also has a list of books (ordered by date) which made it possible to list all the books by an author.

However, unless I'm mistaken, a `Vec` in Rust can't contain references to structures. So, to me it looks like it is not possible to for each `Author` to have a vector of references to the books in the `Library`.

How should I do this? Is it possible to keep this structure without having multiple copies of the same `Book` structure? I would really like to be able to say `Library.get_book(id).set_title("New title")` and then have the title changed in the entire program.

Comment: you can have a vector with references to structures, but then you won't be able to modify the structures anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your code sample already features IDs, the solution can be straightforward:

- the `Library` will have a hash-map or BTree mapping an `BookId` to its `Book`
- all other structures that reference a book do so by having a copy of its `BookId`

And of course you would do the same with `AuthorId` and `Author`.

Another possibility is to use `Rc` and `Weak`, however unless carefully managed you may get memory leaks.

Comment: Ahh, so I assume you have a HashMap of <Key, &reference>? If that is the case the solution is of course obvious. I guess I sort of assumed that was not an option since you could not have a vector of references

Comment: @PeterLudvigsen: You can have a vector of references, in general, if you can prove to the compiler that the references will outlive the vector. However in your case the references point into a sibling of the vector, and thus you cannot prove it. Thus, you will have a `BTreeMap<BookId, Book>` and a `BTreeMap<AuthorId, Author>` as the "authoritative" sources of data, and then your `Author` can contain a `Vec<BookId>`.